# Android on demand dynamic-feature - for xml and image resources

Tags: android, android-studio, dynamic-feature-module, dynamic-feature

When I run the `Analyze App size...` plugin, I am getting following in Android Studio.

```
Place large file app/src/main/res/drawable/my_activity.xml inside an on demand dynamic-feature to avoid bundling in api

Adding large files to an on demand dynamic-feature will allow you to still use the file in your app without including it in your initial download size.
```

I am not sure how to achieve this using on demand dynamic-feature for specific .xml and image resources.

Any suggestions on this is highly appreciated.

Comment: What file size are we talking here? Usually an AVD shouldn't be large enough to validate a separate module.

Comment: How big is your `my_activity.xml`?